# When making simple UPDATE, I'm getting '@P0' inserted into column instead of value I'm passing in

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my asp.net core / EF Core app, if a Customer table stripe_customerID field is null, I need to generate a new string value and update the customer record.  I'm using the code below to try and do this.

```
Customer = _dbcontext.Customer.FirstOrDefault(m => m.fk_Email == User.Identity.Name);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Customer.stripe_CustomerID))
{
   string NewStripeCustomerID = "abc123";
   var result = _dbcontext.Database
   //.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"EXECUTE UpdateStripeCustomerID @StripeCustomerID='{NewStripeCustomerID}', @CustomerID={Customer.CustomerID}");
   .ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE Customer SET stripe_CustomerID='{NewStripeCustomerID}' WHERE CustomerID={Customer.CustomerID}");
```

When I run this using either the direct UPDATE sql raw command, or using the commented out stored procedure, both set the field to the value '@p0'

```
stripe_CustomerID
@p0
```

To make matters more confusing, when I pause the debugger on the line, and copy the interpolated string, I get:

```
$"EXECUTE UpdateStripeCustomerID @StripeCustomerID=N'{NewStripeCustomerID}', @CustomerID={Customer.CustomerID}" = "EXECUTE UpdateStripeCustomerID @StripeCustomerID='abc123', @CustomerID=1"
```

Which looks exactly right, and if I execute it in MSSSMS, it of course works fine.

I'm at a loss why @p0 is being inserted.

Comment: Remove the single quotes here `stripe_CustomerID='{NewStripeCustomerID}'` since `{NewStripeCustomerID}` will be passed as parameter. Automatically binding parameters is the whole purpose of `Interpolated` method. What you see in the debugger is what you'll get if you use `Raw` method, because the debugger is converting the interpolated string to regular string.

Comment: wow... yup <slaps head>  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 .ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE Customer SET stripe_CustomerID = '{NewStripeCustomerID}' WHERE CustomerID = {Customer.CustomerID}");
```

Single quote (`'`) is not needed for `{NewStripeCustomerID}`.

Try this:

```
 .ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE Customer SET stripe_CustomerID = {NewStripeCustomerID} WHERE CustomerID = {Customer.CustomerID}");
```

Please also share stored procedure code.